# Updating a JavaScript Object Creation Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, design-patterns

I have the following JavaScript pattern for creating a simple plugin:

```
(function(window, document, $) {

    function method_1(){

    }

    function method_2{}
    {

    }

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

I want to have the ability to access my plugin and plugin methods in the following way:

```
myplugin.method_1();
myplugin.method_2();
```

How do I update my existing plugin pattern to enable this?!

**NOTE**: It has to maintain a self-executing format i.e. no variable declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern seems to work perfectly for my requirements:

```
(function(root, name, make){
    var $ = root['jQuery'] || root['Zepto'];
    if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module['exports']) module['exports'] = make($);
    else root[name] = make($);
}(window, 'myPlugin', function($) {

    function method_1(){

    }

    function method_2{}
    {

    }

    var myPlugin = {
        method_1: method_1,
        method_2: method_2
    };
    return myPlugin;

}));
```

Comment: Ugh! Your `this` is defaulting to the global `window` object. I'd suggest that you pass in the window object explicitly as a parameter alongside 'myPlugin'

Comment: @I-LinKuo Ok. How about now?!

Comment: That's definitely much better.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napple/qzM96/2/), which returns an object that includes the public functions for the plugin.

```
var myPlugin = (function(window, document, $) {
    function privateFunction() {
    }

    return {
        method_1: function () {
        },
        method_2: function () {
            privateFunction(); // This works
        }
    };

}(window, document, jQuery));

myPlugin.method_1();
myPlugin.method_2();
myPlugin.privateFunction(); // This will throw an error
```

Comment: Thanks. Just clarified the question further. I need it to be self-executing without the variable declaration.

Comment: I found something close to what I would want to achieve here: [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryanve/response.js/master/response.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryanve/response.js/master/response.js). Based on the way it runs, I can use it, but I have no idea how it works?!

Comment: Oh ok, I think I get it now. Will post answer later.